# Firebase Cloud Messaging and battery draining on not-used apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-background

I have noticed that my apps do big battery drain (about 15% for example) sometime according to battery stats even if it was not used (0 foreground time and 0 background time). It happens even in doze when I sleep and background restrictions doesn't help. The common thing in those apps is FCM.

I have checked them with optimizer and every thing looks normal.
Is that possible that FCM drains battery or could it be system stats mistake?

I observed it with apps like 9gag, reddit too. I think they could use FCM.
Is that any way to see some detailed battery stats?
I use Pixel 3a - Android 10.